# Calculate Fiscal |Year

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add a fiscal year column.  Our fiscal year looks like this Q1 apr-jun,  Q2 jul-sept, Q3 oct-dec, Q4 jan-mar

I have the column 'TimeOfCall' which displays

```
2013-01-26 07:44:51.000
2014-03-12 13:21:34.000 
2015-12-25 16:25:21.000  etc
```

Searching the forum i have tried using the following. For the date 2015-12-25 this gives the fiscal year as 2016.  I need it to be 2015.

```
case when month(timeofcall) >4
then year(timeofcall) +1
else year(timeofcall) 
end as fiscal
```

Ideally I'd like the output to look like

```
TimeoFCall                      Fiscal Year
2013-01-26 07:44:51.000            2012-13
2014-03-12 13:21:34.000            2013-12
2015-12-25 16:25:21.000            2015-16
```

but this would suffice

```
TimeoFCall                      Fiscal Year
2013-01-26 07:44:51.000             2012
2014-03-12 13:21:34.000             2013
2015-12-25 16:25:21.000             2015
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems like adding a "Fiscal year" column is just duplicate information of what is in "Time of call", so if possible, I would avoid creating the "Fiscal year" column. Instead, it probably be better to compute the fiscal year from "Time of call" every time you need it. If this to much work for your servers, use some sort of cache that is separate from your database. This way your database has the minimum data you need, and derived data like "Fiscal year" lives somewhere else.

Comment: Also, in your expected output, you meant to write `2013-14` instead of `2013-12`, no?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: date & time functions differ a lot, what is your dbms please? MySQL? Sybase? DB2? Postgres? Oracle? MS SQL Server? Terradata? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? It says "if april and up, take the current year, else, take the previous year". For instance, April 2015 is fiscal year 2015, but March 2015 is fiscal year 2014.

```
case when month(timeofcall) >= 4
then year(timeofcall)
else year(timeofcall) - 1
end as fiscal
```

Comment: brilliant, i think that's it. Thank you

Comment: @whitz11: Awesome ! If this works for you, please consider accepting this answer by checking the "Tick" sign and upvoting the answer. You can also upvote comment that have helped you to encourage StackOverflow members to continue supporting you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is "extract the year after subtracting 3 months", e.g. Oracle syntax:

```
extract(year from add_months(timeofcall,-3))
```

Of course you should also have a calendar where things like that are precalculated...